# IQueryable efficiency

Tags: c#, linq

I'm writing a repositoy now, returning IQueryable results. Does adding filters affect the efficiency? campring to write the clause in the linq.

Such as

```
IQueryable result = repository.GetAllBooks().Where(book => book.author =="Russell");
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An equivalent LINQ statement would compile to the Where extension method that you use above so it should behave/perform in the same way.